# If condition on $a$ is given, then find the domain of the function

Tags: calculus, functions

If $\log _{\frac{1}{3}} (|a|+1)>-1$, then find the domain of

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2x^4+ax^3-6x^2-4ax-8}$$

Using $\log _{\frac{1}{3}} (|a|+1)>-1$, I got $-2<a<2$ but to use it in $\sqrt{2x^4+ax^3-6x^2-4ax-8} \geq0$

Could someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$$2x^4+ax^3-6x^2-4ax-8=2x^4-6x^2-8+ax(x^2-4)=\\=2(x^4-3x^2-4)+ax(x^2-4)=2(x^2-4)(x^2+1)+ax(x^2-4)=(x^2-4)(2x^2+ax+2)\\$$
NOTE:For factoring $x^4-3x^2-4$ you can use the change of variables $t=x^2$ and use a quadratic.

Comment: Brilliant. How did you observe this? Could you share a bit of your thought process?

Comment: My thought was that you can't find a domain of a fourth power polynomial and even harder with a parameter,derivatives also won't help much,so the second thought was that when you group terms by $a$ you will get $x^2-4$ now on first look it's possible that the rest of polynomial shares at least the $(x-2)$ factor or in best case whole $x^2-4$